# Express a string as a function in R

Tags: r

I am automating the creation of a series of plots each of which is based on a class of chemicals (e.g., metals, PCBs, etc.); for reasons I'll leave out, I am plotting the legend outside of the plot and using negative values for the `inset` argument for the `legend()` function to do this (e.g., `inset = c(-0.2, 0)`). As each of the chemical classes requires different values for the `inset` I thought of creating a hash table using the `hash` package to store the values needed for each chemical class. However, in order to store these in the hash table I was storing the vector of values as a string (e.g., "c(-0.2, 0)").

My code for the hash table looks like this:
`legend.hash <- hash(chem.class, c('c(-0.2, 0)', 'c(-0.2, 0)', 'c(-0.25, -0.4)', 'c(-0.25, -0.3)', 'c(-0.2, 0)', 'c(-0.4, -0.2)', 'c(-0.2, 0)', 'c(-0.2, 0)'))`
 where `chem.class` is a vector of chemical classes.

Retrieving the values from the resulting hash table are obviously as a string `"c(-0.2, 0)"`, is there a way of converting this string of text so that R interprets it as a function that could be used like the following: `legend(..., inset = legend.hash[[chem.class[i]]])`?

Or is there a better way to implement this using the traditional graphics system?

Comment: Why can't you simply use a list?

Comment: I'd be curious to see an example where you *really* need multiple values of insets to plot the legend. It may be much simpler than that.

Comment: The number of items and length of the items within the legend changes drastically (ranging from 1 to over 40 items) through the series of plots. Keeping the insets the same for each plot resulted in the legends extending past the page margins.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The classic way of executing a string as if it was a function is by using `eval()` and `parse()` :

```
> eval(parse(text="c(-0.2,0)"))
[1] -0.2  0.0
```

But I really wonder why you insist on using a hash instead of a simple list.

```
 legend.hash <- list(c(-0.2, 0), c(-0.2, 0), c(-0.25, -0.4), c(-0.25, -0.3), 
                 c(-0.2, 0), c(-0.4, -0.2), c(-0.2, 0), c(-0.2, 0))
 names(legend.hash) <- chem.class
```

would allow you to use the exact construct you're using now, without all the tricky bits and pieces of `eval()` and `parse()`, especially thinking about the infamous `fortune(106)` :

```
> require(fortunes)
> fortune(106)

If the answer is parse() you should usually rethink the question.
   -- Thomas Lumley
      R-help (February 2005)
```

Comment: Perfect. To be honest, the utility of lists sometimes escapes me. It's clear I need to spend some more time with them. Thanks! Also -- thanks for the extra wisdom :)

Comment: Just to follow up, would one use a hash table over a list purely for the speed increase?

Comment: For examples of this size I would expect the speed difference of hash over list to be negligible (unless you were performing the operation millions of times), and probably (???) completely negated by the need to `eval(parse())` to get the strings back into the appropriate numeric-vector format ...

Answer (score 1):

It may work better to position your legend using the `grconvertX` and `grconvertY` functions rather than using negative insets.

Comment: is this an answer or a comment ... ?

Comment: It is meant as an answer to the very last line in the original question on there being a better way to position the legend than converting strings.

Answer (score 1):

If you really want to convert a string with 2 number values in it into a vector of numbers then consider using the `strapply` function from the `gsubfn` package.  This way you avoid the `parse` function and all the potential headaches that come with it.  It may also end up being faster.

If you change the strings to just the numbers and a seperator (without the 'c' and parens) then you could just use `as.numeric` on the result of `strsplit` which may be even faster.